# WooCommerce Not generating meta id with update_meta_data

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I m using below code to update the custom data to woocommerce order.

```
$order_data = wc_get_order( $post_id );
$order_data->update_meta_data( 'my_data', $existing_labels );
$order_data->save();
```

If i get the saved data using below code it is empty.

```
$order_data->get_meta('my_data');
```

I checked all meta using $order_data->get_meta_data();
I got as below where meta id is not generated by woocommerce thats why the value is not saved in db.

```
        [data:protected] => Array
            (
                [id] =>
                [key] => my_data
                [value] => array("somedata")
            )
```

Can anyone tell me whats wrong with above code ?